# Speed of Water in a River

Tags: water, speed, flow

Does a river flow faster the higher the water level - or does it go at exactly the same speed?

I was recently tubing in a river and the water seemed to be going faster with the water level being higher; this may have just been an error in judgement.  Intuitively, perhaps a higher water level is associated with a higher water pressure, which would lead the river to go faster as in a hose.  But the river is not limited to a space constraint.

Comment: Why would you think it would flow faster? Why would you think it flows the same? Show us some effort of your own.

Comment: You will need to assume something like that the term "*the river flows faster*" means "*more volume of water per second is flowing through a crosssection*". The "speed" of a river is not very specific, since the speed varies from point to point.

Comment: Let's assume that, then.